# How do I justify text in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, terminal

What command could justify text based on terminal width? For example for:

```
text is here text is here text is here text is here text is 
here text is here text is here text is here text is here text
is here text is here text is here text is here
```

I would like to print:

```
   text is here text is here text is here text is here text is
 here text is here text is here text is here text is here text
                is here text is here text is here text is here
```

Comment: Do you want it right-justified to the length of the longest line or to the width of the screen? (The two answers differ on this point, and it's unclear to me which is correct).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: From the appearance of the expected output:: 2nd line starts from very first column is telling me that longest line is taken as the justification margin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  to the width of the screen

Comment: Hmm you edited your question. Anyway in that case your should accept answer from @thatotherguy

Comment: @anubhava Yes, sorry about that. I did not notice that I wrote bad output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` to align and `tput cols` to get the terminal width:

```
width=$(tput cols)
while IFS= read -r line
do 
  printf "%${width}s\n" "$line"
done << EOF
text is here text is here text is here text is here text is
here text is here text is here text is here text is here text
is here text is here text is here text is here
EOF
```

To instead center align from a file:

```
width=$(tput cols)
while IFS= read -r line
do 
  printf "%$((width/2 - ${#line}/2))s%s\n" "" "$line"
done < file
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Probably because COLUMNS isn't exported by default. I edited it to use `tput cols`.

Comment: Confirmed that you're correct on this point. Must say I'm a bit confused, but... *shrug*.

Comment: @thatotherguy How to change this code if i want the text to be centered by the terminal width? Also, how to change this if I need this to be read from file? Thanks.

Comment: @Godfryd that's really a different question, but I updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Using `gnu wc` get the max length of a line from your file
- Use `printf` to right justify the output

**Script:**

```
max=$(wc -L < file) && while read -r p; do printf "%${max}s\n" "$p"; done < file
  text is here text is here text is here text is here text is
here text is here text is here text is here text is here text
               is here text is here text is here text is here
```

Comment: How to change this if I want the text to be centered? Thanks.

Comment: That can be done with little more code, [see this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96115/5839)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
width=$(tput cols)
fmt -w $width | xargs -i printf "%${width}\n" {}
```